# How can I generate a hypothesis strategy to generate a list that contains at least one of each element it samples from?

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

I am looking for a way to build a [Hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) strategy such that each element in a given list is present in the generated list.

e.g.

Assuming that we have

```
values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

we want a strategy that generates lists from given values such that each element appears at least once, e.g.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[2, 1, 0, 3, 5, 8]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[5, 2, 5, 2, 8, 2, 0, 8, 3, 2, 0, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 1]
```

I am getting errors in my program because I need to select a value that does not exist in a list that uses the `sampled_from` strategy. (presumably with a large enough list, the probability that such a value would appear grows, however I am working with expensive objects, and that seems like a workaround)

I have spent quite some time trying to figure out if any of the strategies enforce that certain values will appear in the generated values -- `fixed_dictionaries` seems to be the only one -- and I am struggling to even come up with a simple composite strategy.

Comment: can you please provide an example of such list and desired examples?

Comment: your response is indeed what i was looking for -- thank you. I'll edit OP for clarity.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `strategies.lists` and then concatenate with `values` so that every value is presented and then shuffle

```py
from hypothesis import strategies

sub_values = (strategies.lists(strategies.sampled_from(values))
              .map(lambda sublist: sublist + values)
              .flatmap(strategies.permutations))
```